# Circular dependency - best approach?

Tags: python, python-import, circular-dependency

I Have two three files: `a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py`.

These three files are in different directories (let us call it `a_dir`, `b_dir`, `c_dir`).
First I only had two files `a.py` and `b.py`. `b.py` had this:

```
from root_dir.a_dir import a
...
do something
...
```

Then everything worked. But when I created third file `c.py`, and I imported it to `a.py` like this:

```
from root_dir.c_dir import c
...
do something
...
```

I started getting error that pyton can't import `a` to `b.py`. So I figured it might be circular dependency?
Then I changed how import works in `a.py` like this:

```
def method_with_c_import(s):
    from root_dir.c_dir import c
    ...
    do something inside method
    ...
```

So I used import only in method I needed it (I don't need that import anywhere else and that method is not used in `b.py`.

But is it best approach or maybe there is better way to solve such problem?

As requested error trace (this happens if I put import I added in `a.py` outside method at the beginning of the file):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/cli/server.py", line 97, in preload_registry
    db, registry = openerp.pooler.get_db_and_pool(dbname,update_module=update_module)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 203, in get
    update_module)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 233, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 350, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 256, in load_marked_modules
    loaded, processed = load_module_graph(cr, graph, progressdict, report=report, skip_modules=loaded_modules, perform_checks=perform_checks)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 159, in load_module_graph
    load_openerp_module(package.name)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 415, in load_openerp_module
    getattr(sys.modules['openerp.addons.' + module_name], info['post_load'])()
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 628, in wsgi_postload
    openerp.wsgi.register_wsgi_handler(Root())
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 517, in __init__
    self.load_addons()
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 580, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/server/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/addons/ambulance_system/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    import report
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/addons/ambulance_system/report/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    import marketing_clinic_report
  File "/home/oerp/openerp70/openerp/addons/ambulance_system/report/marketing_clinic_report.py", line 6, in <module>
    from ambulance_system.model import new_medical_card as nmc
ImportError: cannot import name new_medical_card
```

**P.S.** This error is for file I named in question `b.py` (when I changed in `a.py` as written above before error trace).

**Update**
Priority imports for directories:

```
import generic #c.py directory
import model #a.py directory
import report #b.py directory
```

**Update2**

As requested for example to reproduce the problem (`new_medical_card.py` is `a.py`, `marketing_clinic_report.py` is `b.py`, `generic.py` is `c.py`):

**Module files and dirs structure**:

```
ambulance_system/:
  - generic/generic.py
  - model/new_medical_card.py
  - report/marketing_clinic_report.py
```

Imports in all three files:

`generic.py`:

```
import math
```

`new_medical_card.py`:

```
from openerp.osv import osv, orm, fields
import tools
from tools.translate import _
import time
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
ambulance_system.model.generic import generic as grc #This one produces error
```

`marketing_clinic_report.py`:

```
import time
from report import report_sxw
from ambulance_system.model import new_medical_card as nmc
```

As requested **Update3**
init imports:

I already showed main init file (the one in root directory - ambulance_system, but for clarity reasons will post here too:

`__init__.py`
Priority imports for directories:

```
import generic #c.py directory
import model #a.py directory
import report #b.py directory
```

`__init__.py` for generic dir (`c.py`):

```
import generic
```

`__init__.py` for model dir (`a.py`):

```
import new_medical_card
import medical_card_segment_res
import medical_card
import res_partner
import model_request_access
import new_medical_card_requirement
import medical_card_rule
import hr_department_team
```

`__init__.py` for report dir (`b.py`):

```
import card_field_report
import medical_card_field_report
import medical_card_reject_report
import new_medical_card_reject_report
import new_medical_card_field_report
import old_diagnosis_report
import new_diagnosis_report
import old_form_ambulance_usage_report
import new_form_ambulance_usage_report
import medical_card_history
import new_medical_card_history
import new_medical_card_report
import report1
import report2
import marketing_clinic_report
import print_gsc_data
```

Comment: Does the `do something` bit that you've elided include only function and class definitions, or does other stuff actually run when the modules are loaded?

Comment: Are you sure that a circular dependency is needed? From my point of you, circular dependencies are usually a fault in the software design... Why are you not moving the one method that needs the import to the script which provides the module? Another approach: Maybe you can separate module c into two (c_a, c_b)?

Comment: What do you mean other stuff run? There are bunch of classes that use other imported modules in both `a.py` and `b.py`. `b.py` from `a.py` only need one dictionary that defines fields. `c.py` does not have any dependencies, it just have few generic functions that I thought would be better to use somehwere else than in `a.py`, because that one is used for more specific stuff.

Comment: @flammi88 I'm not moving that method to the script, because it manipulates data inside model that is described in `a.py`. And `c.py` is like a helper for `a.py`, because there are general functions that handles general stuff like checking if variable can be integer and so on. Of course I could just write everything I need in `a.py`, but from my stand of point it does not look like general functions should belong there.

Comment: Show the actual trace for the `ImportError`.

Comment: Are all the `__init__.py` empty? If not can you add the imports contained there?

Answer (score 3):

> is it best approach or maybe there is better way to solve such
>   problem?

No, it isn't the best approach! The best approach is:

**Get rid of the circular dependency**.

Really. It just means you have a design problem in those modules. Circular dependencies shouldn't exist in the first place. In fact a lot of programming languages don't allow them in the first place.

You have several options to do that:

- Move the definitions among the three modules so that each module doesn't have to import the other two.
- Move the definitions so that the imports are only "in one direction": e.g. `b` imports `a` and `c` imports `a` and `b`.
- Remove a module. You have decided to split something that is better to keep together. For example `c` may not be required and could have been better to avoid splitting `a` in the first place
- Split some module (e.g. `c`) to group its definitions by dependency. For example `c_a` will contain all the definitions of `c` that rely on `a` and `c_b` all those that rely on `b` *and `c_a` and `c_b` do **not** import each other*.
- Completely rewrite the design of what you are doing. (The circular dependency might be a symptom of a deeper problem...)

---

If, for some evil reason, you do want to keep the circular dependency, you *might* get rid of the erros by placing the `import`s that cause the dependency at the *end* of the file instead of the top.

However this isn't always possible, but it should work if you use the module only inside function definitions.

Also in this way you loose the grouping of `import`s so that you cannot simply look at the top of the module to understand the dependencies of a module... but this is even *worse* when imports are inside functions since you also have to look at *multiple places* in that situation.

Comment: The thing is I don't understand why those files are circular dependent in first place. Because `c` does not depend on anything, `b` depend on `a` and `a` depened on `c`. So shouldn't it be like this `c` <- `a` <- `b`? Also on _init_.py - import priority is like this: `c`, `a`, `b`. Am I thinking wrong and there is still circular dependency giving these circumstances?

Comment: @Andrius Well, to answer that you should really post a minial example that reproduces the problem. My guess is that `a` and/or `b` are importing the `__init__` file somehow, but it's impossible to tell without actual code. In particular in your case if `model` is importing something like `from ambulance_system import X` then you can have problems with your current setup.